# How send email with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've been trying to send a very simple email using a clickable button that should trigger an email to be sent.

Here is my class:

SendVoucherEmail.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendVoucherEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Test Email')
                    ->text('emails.test'); // Blade template for the email body
    }
}
```

EmailController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\SendVoucherEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail(Request $request)
    {
        // Retrieve the email from the request data
        $email = $request->input('email', 'test@gmail.com');

        try {
            // Send the email
            Mail::raw('This is a test email', function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email)->subject('Test Email');
            });

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Email sent successfully'], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to send email. Error: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Route:

```
 Route::post('send-email', [EmailController::class, 'sendEmail'])->name('send-email');
```

/resources/views/email
test.blade.php

```
<p>This is a test email.</p>
```

JS Code

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle button click event
    $('#sendEmailButton').click(function() {
        sendEmail();
    });

    // Function to send the email via AJAX
    function sendEmail() {
        // Make an AJAX POST request to your Laravel backend
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('admin.send-email') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: 'test@gmail.com' // Replace with the recipient email address
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Handle success response
                console.log(response);
                alert('Email sent successfully!');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle error response
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
                alert('Failed to send email. Please try again.');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>

@endsection
```

when I click on Send email the error comes out as: Failed to send email. Please try again.

Could you catch what's the wrong here?

using `php artisan tinker` and creating a test

```
Mail::raw('Testing Mailtrap', function ($message) {
    $message->to('test@gmail.com');
    $message->subject('Mailtrap Test');
});
```

I do receive the test email using mailtrap

please check my code

Comment: `$email = '$request->input('test@gmail.com');'` - Why do you have single quotes around that? `$message->to($email)` will literally be `$message->to('$request->input('test@gmail.com');')`, and `'$request->input('test@gmail.com');'` is not a valid email... Remove those `'` single quotes. Also, `$request->input('test@gmail.com')` is nonsensical too... You don't have an `<input name="test@gmail.com"/>` element..., nor are you sending `data: { 'test@gmail.com': 'test@gmail.com' }` (as that would be really silly...)

Comment: Your code _should_ work if you do `$email = $request->input('email', 'test@gmail.com');`, then the rest of your code. And re-read the documentation on how to get input: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis for your input, however I'm still facing that Failed to send email error

Comment: Also, since you're catching `catch (\Exception $e)`, why don't you either log what `$e` is (`\Log::info($e)`), or disable your `catch()` block and let your error happen so you can see what's going wrong?

Comment: what I did is I edited the line you mentioned to be now ```$email = $request->input('email', 'test@gmail.com');``` For the catch(\Exception) I'm not that expert yet in Laravel, Im still learning forgive me please unless if you want to help me and tell me what to change

Comment: If you edited that line, then please also [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76483594/edit) to show that. In the future, when someone asks you to make a change and you do, it's best to show what you changed  Moving on, you need to debug your code now. Look up how Exceptions work in PHP, and like I said, either remove your `try / catch` so you can let the error happen, so it can be logged to `storage/logs/laravel.log`, or add `\Log::info($e)` to your `catch()` block. I can't help further unless I know what specifically is going wrong, and you need to enable that.

Comment: Alternatively, this could be a `CSRF` issue; I don't see anywhere you're including a TOKEN when making this `POST` request, so you might be getting a `419` error, which would trigger your `error: function()`. Did you check your browser's `Network` tab (F12 > Network) to see what error code you're getting? Documentation for reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf

Comment: okay I checked the browser and i'm seeing an error 404 Not found even though I have a route for it?

Comment: Check the URL that's being `POST`-ed to; the Network tab should be able to tell you that as well as the error code. Is it `http://localhost:8000/send-email`? Or something else? (And thank you for editing )

Comment: I'm getting 404 not found while browsing to /send-email URL that's weird

Comment: Well, browsing to is a `GET` request, but you defined it as `Route::post()`, which is a `POST` request, so a 404 seems correct there.

Comment: You can do `url: "{{ route('send-email') }}"` in your `<script>`, since that seems to be a `.blade.php` file, just don't try to use `{{ ... }}` in a `.js` file directly, as that won't work.

Comment: I've just tried that but still same issue, the script code is inside a blade.php file

Comment: I got this error: ```Route [send-email] not defined. (View: /var/www/resources/views/admin/createVouchers/show.blade.php)```

Comment: `->name('send-email')` - It definitely exists... Are you caching your routes locally? Did you restart your webserver to clear any automatic caching?

Comment: I did a ```php artisan route:clear``` and ```php artisan route:cache``` but same result

Comment: Hmm... Odd. Kill your webserver (i.e. if you're running this via `php artisan serve`, or similar), then run `composer dump-autoload`, then start it up again.

Comment: I'm under apache2 in a linux machine, I did the ```composer dump-autoload``` no luck, this is making me crazy unless the send-email is wrong?

Comment: That looks fine, unless it's nested under a `Route::group()`? If you run `php artisan route:list`, you should be able to find the `/send-email` route and its name.

Comment: I see an error: ```php artisan route:list

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EmailController] does not exist.
``` thank you for being patient me with

Comment: Ah, so you didn't import your `EmailController` in your `routes/web.php` file, also, `'EmailController@sendEmail'` is the "old" syntax for Routes. Change it to `[EmailController::class, 'sendEmail']`, and add at the top of your file `use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EmailController;`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: I moved EmailController to Admin folder but same issue

Comment: Make sure the `namespace` matches; if you moved to `admin` folder, then it should be `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;`

Comment: After placing the EmailController inside admin folder, i get a strange error: ```Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Controller' not found```

Comment: That's because `Controller` has the namespace `App\Http\Controllers`, so you need to import it via `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` if you want to do `class EmailController extends Controller`. Please take a minute to learn how namespaces work, how you import and reference classes, etc etc.

Comment: Correct, now I'm able to see the routes list, ```| POST                                   | admin/send-email                                      | admin.send-email                            | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EmailController@sendEmail                    | web                                         |
```

Comment: Still getting the error: ```Route [send-email] not defined. (View: /var/www/resources/views/admin/createVouchers/show.blade.php)```

Comment: That's correct... Look at the output of `php artisan route:list`; there's a `Name` column, and in that column, you'll see `admin.send-email`. So of course `route('send-email')` isn't going to work, its name is `admin.send-email`, so you need to use `route('admin.send-email')`. Please brush up on how Named Routes work in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes. That all being said, if you're using `->name('send-email')`, it _should_ be `route('send-email')`, unless you're also using some kind of `Route::group()`. But that's what `php artisan route:list` is for 

Comment: The error is gone, thank you, indeed I'm using Route:group(). however I still get Failed to send email please try again

Comment: While inspecting the browser, it shows error 419, check this screenshot https://prnt.sc/-_p-1NNONRCg

Comment: Ok, good, see my comment earlier about `CSRF` tokens; when making a `POST` request in Laravel, you need to include that token, otherwise you get a `419` error. Check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf, and if you get stuck, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76483594/edit) with what you've tried, and we'll debug it.

Comment: while digging into the browser console, I see this error : ```Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.```

Comment: That wouldn't trigger a `419` error though, and you're definitely using `method: 'POST`... What URL is it saying is generating that `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`?

Comment: @TimLewis you are genius my friend, your hint was indeed the issue, the JS code was missing the csrf so the solution was to add it like this:

```
 data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                email: 'test@gmail.com' // Replace with the recipient email address
            },
```

Thank you so much I was able to receive the email

Comment: Oh, ok, excellent  Glad to hear you got it working now!

Comment: Thank you, what is the best approach to figure out if an email is already sent or not, like avoiding duplicate emails being sent

Comment: You'd have to track them in a database or something; with your current code, there is no concept of "has been sent already" (i.e. this code doesn't do any checks, it just sends the email). Even then, sending emails is generally "asynchronous"; the email is sent by your server, and it assumes it has been sent and received, but there isn't really a way to tell without an external service, like MailTrap (or similar; that's the one I've used).